# warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified

Tags: aspectj

I have used aspectj that is in turn used by Allure Reporting tool in my pom.xml. When I run the suite through maven, I get `warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified`

After a while the classes that contain my tests will stop and I get Unreachable browser exception. I run the same suite through testng.xml and works like a charm. I feel that because of this warning, the classes stop getting called.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.unilog.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>standardTemplate.project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ProjectSuite</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
        <compiler.version>1.7</compiler.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <version.allure>1.4.3</version.allure>
        <version.aspectj>1.7.4</version.aspectj>
        <version.cucumber>1.2.0</version.cucumber>
        <version.selenium>2.53.0</version.selenium>
        <version.slf4j>1.7.7</version.slf4j>
        <version.phantomjs>1.9.7</version.phantomjs>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>



    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.pojosontheweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>monte-repack</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${version.selenium}</version>
    </dependency>

 <!-- custom excelread library using apachePOI -->   
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- zipturnaround -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
    <artifactId>zt-zip</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>


 <!-- java mail -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- Selenium and Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.selenium}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>${version.selenium}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- Utils -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.properties</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-loader</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.05</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Allure Reporter -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>${version.allure}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
     <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
                <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>    
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <version>${version.phantomjs}</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                      -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${version.aspectj}/aspectjweaver-${version.aspectj}.jar
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.github.klieber
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            phantomjs-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [0.4,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>install</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>${version.allure}</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Any update on this?

Comment: @paul Any update by any of you guys?

Comment: Nope nobody response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Spring weaver options in Java config class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974584/how-to-set-spring-weaver-options-in-java-config-class)

Comment: Because this old question just popped up in my news feed due to the new answer: The AspectJ warning is most probably not related to the problem. Where is your reproducible test case for this? A POM alone does not explain anything. I see no test, application or aspect code.

Answer (score 4):

aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true">        
        <include within="my.app.*"/>
        <include within="javax.persistence.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="my.app.MyAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: While it removes the warning, it's not the right thing to do unless you really need to weave javax.*.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a file resources/META-INF/aop.xml with the following context that will turn off all warnings:

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-nowarn"/>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: This should be flagged as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as many people mentioned  this is a warning and it's not related to your issue.

Secondly, you should weave javax classes only if you have very specific purpose like weaving an aspect to trace HttpServlet api or some other javax.* stuff.

Finally, if you decided to weave javax.* it's not **terribly** wrong, but it may affect performance.

Btw, there is a bug opened for this warning message: [eclipse bug 365702](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365702)

That said, you should really ignore that warning message.

[some discussion related to allowing to weave javax.*](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149261)

[just another advice similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974584/how-to-set-spring-weaver-options-in-java-config-class)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:
`<argLine> -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${version.aspectj}/aspectjweaver-${version.aspectj}.jar </argLine>`

To this:
`<argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</argLine>`

Comment: This worked for me to remove the error so I gave an upvote, can you please provide an explanation of what this argument is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my jdk to jdk8. It helped me.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in my case issue was here:
was in build pluginManagement
Just delete all unncecery and leave:

```
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
```